# Split message when too many character

Tags: python-3.x, discord

Im currently working with discord with Python 3.9.6 where I am trying to create a embed based on how much text I have.

According to discord:

```
+-------------+------------------------+
|    Field    |         Limit          |
+-------------+------------------------+
| title       | 256 characters         |
| description | 4096 characters*       |
| fields      | Up to 25 field objects |
| field.name  | 256 characters         |
| field.value | 1024 characters        |
| footer.text | 2048 characters        |
| author.name | 256 characters         |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

and what I am trying to achieve is that I want to split into new embed if we reach 1000 characters, as we already know we cannot reach more than 1020 characters for one field.

What I have done so far is:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook

# payload = {
#     "hello": 1,
#     "world": 2,
#     "test": None,
#     "yes": 4
# }

payload = {
    'Hello, everyone! This is the LONGEST TEXT EVER! I was inspired by the various other "longest texts ever" on the internet, and I wanted to make my own.': None,
    'The first time, I didnt save it. The second time, the Neocities editor crashed. Now Im writing this in Notepad,': 50,
    'Waffles is a funny word. Theres a Teen Titans Go episode called "Waffles" where the word "Waffles" is said a hundred-something': 10,
    ' surprised me when I saw the episode for the first time. I speak Pig Latin with my sister sometimes. Its pretty fun. I like speaking i': None,
    'f it ever does, twill be pretty funny. By the way is a word I invented recently, and its a contraction of it will. I really hope it gains popularity in the near future, because Itll is too boring. Nobody likes boring. This is nowhere near being the longest text ever, but eventually it will be! I mig': 10,
    'No, Im not. I should probably get some sleep. Goodnight! Hello, Im back again. I basically have only two interests nowaday': 20,
    ' I would like to have a fursuit, go to furry conventions, all that stuff. But for now I can only dream of that. Sorry you had to deal with me talking about furries, but Im honestly very desperate for this to be the longest text ever. Last night I': 13
}
embed = DiscordEmbed(color=8149447)

stock = sum(v for v in payload.values() if v)

texts = [f"{k} - ({v})" if v else k for k, v in payload.items()]

character_count, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(texts):

    if len(item) + character_count > 900:
        embed.add_embed_field(
            name="Text",
            value="\n".join(texts[i:j])
        )
        character_count, i = len(item), j
    else:
        character_count += len(item)

if character_count:
    embed.add_embed_field(
        name="Text",
        value="\n".join(texts[i:])
    )

if stock:
    embed.add_embed_field(
        name="Total Stock",
        value=stock
    )
# Insert ur own discord URL (The URL here is not real)
webhook = DiscordWebhook(
    url="https://discord.com/api/webhooks/788360382141825054/m_Et9RT5f9AReTQuVuJJ4Qk60ETEe1KcezBRuGc2HlWyXdTgKpOjUI5u39NGvoFhfsy8"
)
webhook.add_embed(embed)
response = webhook.execute()
```

There is different scenario I am trying to achieve:

1. If we have a value in the key, then I want to sum it up to a "stock" variable and also add `"- (n)`" in the text `texts = [f"{k} - ({v})" if v else k for k, v in payload.items()]`
2. I would like to print out the whole stock if we have a stock value (e.g. if I set all the values as `None`that could be a scenario
3. If we reach more than 1000 characters of a embed field, we should create a new field embed and continue to print out the key-values that have not been embeded yet.

Looking forward learn new stuff!

How I would like to have it: See where it does a break on every end of the text
[image: How I would like to have it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall your algorithm is pretty reasonable, but it needs to be pulled out into a function, and type hints will help. Your input type is a sequence since it needs to be indexed, and your output is an iterable.

Rather than having an `if` statement that increments or assigns to your count, conditionally assign 0 to your count and unconditionally increment.

If your maximum field length is 1024, why are you splitting at 900?

Your colour constant should be represented in hex, i.e. `0x7C59C7`, and not decimal.

Move your calculation for total stock closer to where it's used.

### Suggested

```py
from typing import Optional, Dict, Iterable, Sequence

from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook


def group_by_len(items: Sequence[str], max_len: int = 1024) -> Iterable[str]:
    start, count = 0, 0

    for end, item in enumerate(items):
        n = len(item)
        if n + count >= max_len:
            yield '\n'.join(items[start: end])
            count = 0
            start = end
        count += n

    if count > 0:
        yield '\n'.join(items[start:])

payload: Dict[str, Optional[int]] = { ... }

embed = DiscordEmbed(color=0x7C59C7)
texts = [f"{k} - ({v})" if v else k for k, v in payload.items()]

for paragraph in group_by_len(texts):
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Text", value=paragraph)

stock = sum(v for v in payload.values() if v)
if stock > 0:
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Total Stock", value=stock)

# Insert your own discord URL (The URL here is not real)
webhook = DiscordWebhook(
    url="https://discord.com/api/webhooks/788360382141825054"
        "/m_Et9RT5f9AReTQuVuJJ4Qk60ETEe1KcezBRuGc2HlWyXdTgKpOjUI5u39NGvoFhfsy8"
)
webhook.add_embed(embed)
response = webhook.execute()
```

Comment: Hi! I was almost pretty sure that I did a really great job but as usual you chock me again. I have tried to run your suggested script and I got an error saying `yield '\n'.join(items[start: end]), TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: My mistake; please try with the edit.

Comment: Works now! Its actually really nice! I have again no words to say than thank you. I would not have came up with this solution but its really nice and less complicated than mine. I will try to understand more the group_by_len as I dont fully get it 100% but with some debugging that should help me out. Thanks once again!